# Python: Import /etc/services file to a Dictionary

Tags: python, linux, dictionary, format

So I have to create a python script that will import `/etc/services` file and write it to a dictionary.

The goal is that the port/protocol will become the key and service the value. 
I want to be able to print the dict entering the key info and see the service return as such:

```
print(yourdictionaryname["22/tcp"])
ssh
```

This script is the furthest I have been able to get. I found it online and it works great but it is designed to just show unused ports. Cant seem to modify it to do what i need:

```
# set the file name depending on the operating system
if sys.platform == 'win32':
file = r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\services'
else:
file = '/etc/services'

# Create an empty dictionary
ports = dict()

# Iterate through the file, one line at a time
for line in open(file):

# Ignore lines starting with '#' and those containing only whitespace
if line[0:1] != '#' and not line.isspace():

   # Extract the second field (seperated by \s+)
   pp = line.split(None, 1)[1]

   # Extract the port number from port/protocol
   port = pp.split ('/', 1)[0]

   # Convert to int, then store as a dictionary key
   port = int(port)
   ports[port] = None

   # Give up after port 200
   if port > 200: break

# Print any port numbers not present as a dictionary key
for num in xrange(1,201):
if not num in ports:
    print "Unused port", num
```

Comment: sounds like there are two tasks involved in the assignment: 1) Writing the dictionary to a file. 2) Parsing that dictionary file for the port/service? Which part are you stuck on? Start by getting the dictionary (I think this script already does that) and write it out to a file. Then do step 2

Comment: the answer to this question [How to write a dictionary into a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20169670/1248974),  shows how to save the dictionary (`ports` is the dictionary in the script you posted) to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had to look all around to get this to work. It is a cool function. First it detects the OS then it creates a dictionary based on the /etc/services file. Next it will parse that file for port input then return the associated service.

```
import sys
import os

# set the file name depending on the operating system
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    file = os.environ.get('WINDIR', r'C:\WINDOWS') + r'\system32\drivers\etc\services'
else:
    file = '/etc/services'

# Create an empty dictionary
ports = dict()

# Iterate through the file, one line at a time
for line in open(file):

    if line[0:1] != '#' and not line.isspace():
        k = line.split(None, )[1]

        # Extract the port number from port/protocol
        v = line.split('/', )[0]
        j = ''.join([i for i in v if not i.isdigit()])
        l = j.strip('\t')
        ports[k] = l

print(ports.get("22/tcp"))
print(ports.get("8080/tcp"))
print(ports.get("53/udp"))
```

Comment: @PhilipCouling  - In such a case we just change the `file` variable. The ask here wasn't to find the file (nor was it related to Windows) but simply given that `/etc/services` file how do we convert it to a dictionary where the port/protocol will yield the service

Comment: The downvote was for something other than the comment.  7 years old or not it's still pulling links from google. The point is to avoid triping up readers neadlessly. Not really sure the point of arguing against it.  Seems more energy than the fix was.

Answer (score 4):

depending on what you're trying to accomplish, the [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getservbyname) module may be sufficient for your needs, with its `getservbyname` and `getservbyport` functions:

```
>>> socket.getservbyport(22)
'ssh'
>>> socket.getservbyport(22, 'udp')
'ssh'
>>> socket.getservbyport(22, 'tcp')
'ssh'
>>> socket.getservbyname('http')
80
>>> socket.getservbyname('http', 'tcp')
80
>>> socket.getservbyname('http', 'udp')
80
```

if you really need the dict, you could iterate over `range(1, 65536)` with `getservbyport`.

Comment: Does that actually show running services or is it just common ones

Comment: it reads /etc/services for you. so it contains all known services, not just the ones currently running.